# Find the pattern of the sequence of prime numbers 17 23 5 1013 2027 13

Tags: number-sequence, sequence

A friend gave me a sequence of prime numbers 17 23 5 1013 2027 13 and said that they have a pattern. I tried to find something but I am stumped by the fact that the numbers first increase, then kill, increase and then decrease again. How do I find the next number?

Comment: I think your friend might have made a mistake and perhaps should have put 1019 instead of 1013?

Comment: I asked, and he said he was sure he did.

Comment: If you have a second question with different numbers, ask a new question. Do not alter this question in any way that invalidates the provided answer.

Answer (score 14):

These are

> the largest prime factors of the numbers 2023-2028.

The next number is:

> 2029, a prime!